# Creating multiple objects of the same instance and then list them in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to create multiple objects of the same instance automatically (i.e. without giving much data in the post request) in Django Rest Framework and then return a list of these objects.

So let's say I have this model:

```
class City(models.Model):
    ...

class House(models.Model):
    city = models.Foreignkey(City, ...)
    ...

class Resident(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, ...)
```

I now want to be able to hit a route with a postrequest like this:

```
localhost:8000/api/city/createresidents/
```

And get back JSON like this:

```
{
  [
    {
      residentid = "<some_number>",
      residentname = "<some_name>",
    },
    {
      residentid = "<some_number>",
      residentname = "<some_name>",
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

And in the body of the postrequest I append information about the House and the created residents, maybe which street it is, what last name the residents have, or some other data about the house or the residents from their respective model.

How would I go about doing that if the view should allways create, let's say 4 residents?

I tried modifying the `perform_create()` method of the `CreateModelMixin` but I couldn't get it to work.

### Edit

I realise that I didn't write my question clearly enough.

I want the post body data to only look like this:

```
{
  "house": "<some_house_id>"
}
```

So that then Django knows where the house is (meaning which restaurant it belongs to) and that Django creates 4 residents with hardcoded inputs, except that they automatically get assigned to that house.

Comment: Can you add an example of the `POST` data?

Comment: @jerin-peter-george thank you for your help. I edited the post to make my question more clearly :)

Answer (score 0):

So the way I now came up with was to create the following view:

```
class CreateResidentList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                         mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                         generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = StampSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsGod)

    def get_queryset(self):
        residents = Resident.objects.filter(house__id=self.kwargs['house'])
        return stamps

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'house' in request.data:
            house = House.objects.get(id=request.data['house'])
            while(house.resident_set.all().count() < 500):
                self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Please give me feedback on whether this is good python / django code :)
On my server this works as intended, but I'm not sure, If I copied it here correctly.